# Sorting on embedded object apply sort clausole only to last property

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

```
@Embeddable
@Value
public class Version
{
    int major;
    int minor;
    int patch;
}

@Entity
public class CodeAndVersionEntity extends PanacheEntityBase
{
    @Id
    public String code;
    
    @Embedded
    public Version version;
    
    public static Collection<CodeAndVersionEntity> listOrdered()
    {
        return CodeAndVersionEntity.list("from CodeAndVersionEntity", Sort.descending("versione"));
    }
}
```

Generate query:

```
select
    codeandver0_.code as code1_0_,
    codeandver0_.major as major2_0_,
    codeandver0_.minor as minor3_0_,
    codeandver0_.patch as patch4_0_ 
from
    CodeAndVersionEntity codeandver0_ 
order by
    codeandver0_.major,
    codeandver0_.minor,
    codeandver0_.patch desc
```

Are there any ways to let Hibernate generate the right `order by` clause as:

```
order by
    codeandver0_.major desc,
    codeandver0_.minor desc,
    codeandver0_.patch desc
```

other than specify all properties in sort clause as `Sort.descending("versione.major","versione.minor","versione.patch")`?

I'm using Quarkus 2.6.2.Final with Hibernate 5.6.1.Final.